# Can we use Mockito and PowerMockito for same junit test class

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have a java class which has only one `method`, inside that method I am creating `object for another class`, so I am using `PowerMockito.whenNew(fullyQualifiedClassName).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockObject);`. In the same method I have to mock another `method(non-static)` as well so I have to use `Mockito` here like `Mockito.when(mockObject.method1(1000)).thenReturn(createdObject);//showing error here`. I am getting errors as below

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.tocassandra.DMCassandraTest.test(DMCassandraTest.java:38)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before         'thenReturn' instruction if completed

at com.tocassandra.DMCassandraTest.test(DMCassandraTest.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I declared `Junit Test class` with annotations

`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({NewObjectClass.class})`

Sample code:-

Original Method looks like as below

```
public static void insertData(String name) throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SampleA sample = new SampleA("args1","arg2",4);

    sample.subscribe(name); //its a void method
    logger.info("subscibed to the topic {}", ConsumerTopicName);
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(CASSANDRA_CONNECTION_HOST.split(",")).build();
    session = cluster.connect(KEYSPACE);

    try {

        while (true) {
            try {
                SampleRecords records = sample.getRecords("argValue");
                for (Record record : records) {

                    A a = mapper.readValue(record.value(), A.class);

                    dao.insertData(session, a);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Exception while reading data from kafka", ex);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

Test Class:-

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SampleA.class})
public class DMCassandraTest {

SampleA sample = Mockito.mock(SampleA.class);
@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    String name = "test";
    PowerMockito.whenNew("org.companny.SampleA").withAnyArguments().thenReturn(sample);
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer(){

        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            sample.subscribe(name);
            return null;
        }

    }).when(SampleA.class);
    // Above code is to mock void subscribe method in insertData, even I am 
    // not sure whther it works or not
    SampleRecords records = new SampleReccords();
    // setting values to records
    Mockito.when(sample.getRecords("argdValue")).thenReturn(records);
    insertToCassandra.insertData(name);
}
}
```

Comment: You can use Powermockito to mock and do exactly the same thing you are doing with Mockito. For now I have two notes, Is your `mockObject` properly anotated/mocked? And can you show the definition of `method1`. That is why we always ask for people here to show at least the relevant part of the code. Cheers

Comment: Added sample code, can you pls check it now

Comment: Where is the definition of `consumer` ? You are using it here: `Mockito.when(consumer.getRecords("argdValue"))`

Comment: I just edited it... now check it

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is this block:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer(){

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        sample.subscribe(name);
        return null;
    }

}).when(SampleA.class);
```

Mockito is asking you, "When *what*?"  You don't specify when Mockito's mock should answer back.  Logically it seems like you want to do this after `subscribe`.

However, being honest, I don't see much opportunity (or reason) to mock.  The instances you get are concretely defined and can't be easily injected in to add variance to their values.  My recommendation would be to *not* mock these out until you can inject `SampleA` somewhere so that adding a mock is less cumbersome than relying on PowerMockito.

Comment: remoed above `doAnswer` code but still getting an error like `main ERROR Could not reconfigure JMX java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"`